# VS Code SSH extension - Ripgrep search fails with "Unsupported system page size" error on Rocky Linux 8.7

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, ssh, rocky-os

I'm using VS Code with the SSH extension to connect to a remote server running Rocky Linux 8.7. When I try to perform a Ripgrep search on a folder in my project, the search fails with the following error message in the VS Code SSH logs:

```
<jemalloc>: Unsupported system page size
memory allocation of 5 bytes failed
```

[image]

The search works fine when performed locally or on other Linux versions, but fails only on Rocky Linux 8.7 through the SSH extension.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue with VS Code and the SSH extension on Rocky Linux 8.7? Is there any workaround or solution to this problem?

### Update

- Fixed on later versions of rocky
- If 8.7 is a must, a workaround at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/6930#issuecomment-1216988454